# Extracting xts attributes from an xts object

Tags: r, xts

Assume an `xts` object `obj` as in the following example:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols.FRED('USAPFCEQDSMEI', env = globalenv())
obj <- base::get('USAPFCEQDSMEI')
```

By examining the structure of it, `str(obj)`, the following is returned:

```
An ‘xts’ object on 1960-01-01/2020-01-01 containing:
  Data: num [1:241, 1] 8.16e+10 8.31e+10 8.30e+10 8.35e+10 8.36e+10 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "USAPFCEQDSMEI"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "FRED"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2020-05-19 19:23:03"
```

I can see that there is a List of 2 `xts` attributes available with the data object: `src` and `updated`, but can't find a way to extract these. None of the classic `unlist` or `obj$src` seems to work.

How to properly extract `src` and `updated` fields in such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `xtsAttributes` to access these attributes.

```
xtsAttributes(obj)
$src
[1] "FRED"

$updated
[1] "2020-05-19 18:29:26 CEST"
```

Or seperately:

```
xtsAttributes(obj)$src
[1] "FRED"

xtsAttributes(obj)$updated
[1] "2020-05-19 18:29:26 CEST"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R alternative to the special `xtsAttributes` function that @phiver showed:

```
attributes(obj)$src
[1] "FRED"

attributes(obj)$updated
[1] "2020-05-19 12:37:31 EDT"
```

As noted in `help(xtsAttributes)`:

> Since xts objects are S3 objects with special attributes, a method is necessary to properly assign and view the user-added attributes.

Therefore, do not attempt this:

```
###Don't do this###
#attributes(obj)$src <- "AAPL"
```